# Is it possible to use different apps as git submodules in a nx workspace?

Tags: git, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I want to build a nestjs backend which is used by a angular frontend application. Each of them for now in a single repository. I stumbled over nrwl-nx for monorepo tooling and am really intrigued to use it.

But my question now is: is it possible to have different apps in the workspace, but each as an own git submodule? Like so:

```
workspace_folder
|- apps
|  |- application1 <--- git submodule 1
|  |- application2 <--- git submodule 2
|- libs
|...
```

How would the process be to set them up correctly? Can it be done completely by the nx CLI? I couldn't find anything specific to that in the nx documentation.

Comment: And maybe you find a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 5):

Yes! I believe you can do this using Yarn workspace in conjunction with Nx tooling.

So in essence you need to navigate to your apps folder and run:

- `git submodule add https://github.com/[URL for your application 1] application1`
- `git submodule add https://github.com/[URL for your application 2] application2`

More Details here: https://blog.nrwl.io/dev-workflow-using-git-submodules-and-yarn-workspaces-14fd06c07964

An example will be like this: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-example-multirepo